# Read facebook contact from content resolver

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts, android-contentresolver

I have some facebook contacts synchronized in my device with their email, I try to read all contacts stored in my device like this

```
Cursor c = resolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, 
Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", 
new String[] { Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE }, 
Data.CONTACT_ID);
```

I can read all my contact who have email or phone, but facebook contact are not gotten and I want to read also them. Any help